# adding div and input box

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to be able to do a quick calculation where I add the contents of a div and input. I can do this with 2 inputs but can't figure out how to do it this way. My attempts at coding have got me here:

```js
var one = document.getElementById('one'),
  two = document.getElementById('calculate'),
  total = document.getElementById('total');
document.getElementById('calculate').onchange = function() {
  total.innerHTML = parseInt(one.innerHTML) + parseInt(two.innerHMTL);
};
```

```html
<div id="one">11</div>

<input type=number value=2 id="calculate">

<div id="total">0</div>
```

I tried changing "parseInt(two.innerHTML)" to "parseInt(two)" but it was unsuccessful. I get the NotANumber/NaN error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since `two` in you case is an `input` tag it doesn't have the `innerHTML`. Use `value` attribute instead. so it'll look like this:

```
document.getElementById('calculate').onchange = function() {
    total.innerHTML = parseInt(one.innerHTML) + parseInt(two.value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To get value from a input tag use `.value` `document.getElementById('input').value`

So in your case try  `parseInt(two.value)`